# How to fix 'Firebase error: Incorrect database name'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in the middle of making a quick web app and set up a client-side firebase connection. Following the docs, I added the below code to my `index.html` before any other scripts are loaded in my `head`. However, whenever I try to get any kind of information from the database, I get the following error: `@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (...)`

I've tried following the docs about setting up a web app again, and copied the full config info. However, I keep getting the same error. I've checked that my database name is correct in the Firebase console.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-app.js"</script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "..."
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

I appreciate your time and suggestions.

Comment: The `...` is filled in with the real info in my code

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have typed correctly with extension:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Comment: It's all correct. I copied it from Firebase and double-checked myself.